# Create Guid PK in Database VS. in Code

Tags: sql-server, database, architecture

What is "better" generating Primary Keys on the database or generating them in application code, specifically when using GUID/UniqueIdentifier datatype for the keys.

I have read up on the difference between using Guid's and int data types, and it sounds like Guids are feasable for so called "generating offline".

E.g.

instead of having a `NEWID()` contstraint in the database, In one project (where we are using Entity Framework) we use in the application code `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate the PK when inserting data.

**Is this a bad approach ?**

My concerns are:

- Database indexes: Database performance because Id's might not be sequential
- The one in 64 billion chance that the key is already used. (considering that the application will not be enormous but may need room to grow)
- Perhaps there are other disadvantages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well actually, GUID could be sequential from SQL Server 2005. There is a function in named `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` , link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786)

> Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by
>   this function on a specified computer since Windows was started. After
>   restarting Windows, the GUID can start again from a lower range, but
>   is still globally unique. When a GUID column is used as a row
>   identifier, using NEWSEQUENTIALID can be faster than using the NEWID
>   function. This is because the NEWID function causes random activity
>   and uses fewer cached data pages. Using NEWSEQUENTIALID also helps to
>   completely fill the data and index pages.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the NEWSEQUENTIALID() sorry thats sort of what I meant with "NEWID()" That doesn't really speak to my question which is whether it is better to create in database or in code, or rather is it ok to create in code?

Comment: I think it's ok to create in code. As far as I know, guid is generated based on the time of the server, the mac address or the ip address(not sure). Cannot think of any key differences. :)